# I want to add mouseover event to my code using raphael?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, raphael, circle-pack

```
var raphael = new Raphael(document.body,500,500);
raphael.setStart();
var d3_raphael = d3.raphael(raphael);
var stuff = {className:"", children:[
{className:"TVI",  packageName:'aa', value:2000},
{className:"SIC",  packageName:'aa', value:1520},
{className:"RTP1", packageName:'bb', value: 1400},
{className:"SIC",  packageName:'aa', value:1220},
{className:"RTP1", packageName:'bb', value: 1100},
{className:"SIC",  packageName:'aa', value:920},
{className:"RTP1", packageName:'bb', value: 800},
{className:"SIC",  packageName:'aa', value:1520},
{className:"RTP1", packageName:'bb', value: 1400},
{className:"SIC",  packageName:'aa', value:1220},
{className:"RTP1", packageName:'bb', value: 1100},
{className:"SIC",  packageName:'aa', value:920},
{className:"RTP2  manoj", packageName:'bb', value: 550}
]};

var r = 400,
format = d3.format(",d"),
fill = d3.scale.category10();

var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
.sort(function(a, b) {return b.value - a.value;})
.size([r, r]);

 var chart = d3_raphael.select("body").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", r)
.attr("height", r)
.attr("class", "bubble");    
 var node = chart.selectAll("circle")
.data(bubble.nodes(stuff))
.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("cx",function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy",function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.packageName); })
    .mouseover(function() { 
    circle.append("<p>MouseOver</p>");
});
```

but it's giving me error that
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'mouseover'`. i want to add all the mouse over events on it

How to resolve this issue.

Comment: are you sure this is Raphael? Looks more like d3.js to me.

Comment: Actually it's d3 but i am making it compatible with lower versions of ie. i am editing my post see it again.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this in d3 is to use the `on()` function:

```
.on("mouseover", function() { 
    d3.select(this).append("<p>MouseOver</p>");
});
```

Note that `<p>` tags won't work in SVG -- you could however use `foreignObject`. See for example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1424037).

Comment: Thanks Lars...  But i am using                                                         var raphael = new Raphael(document.body,500,500);
raphael.setStart();
var d3_raphael = d3.raphael(raphael); so it is not working it's giving me uncaught exception.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'mouseover'

Comment: I'm not calling a method "mouseover" in the code I posted. Have you tried that?

Comment: I didn't get. What you want me to try?

Comment: Hmm, this should be working. Can you provide a complete example (e.g. on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) please?